# Browser language detection and redirect vs Google Robots

Tags: php, angular, symfony

I try to automatically detect browser language and redirect user to proper page according to his language. Site is bilingual, default language is Polish, second one is English. People with default language different from Polish are redirected to English version.

I found a solution in other questions here, and as a result I created an action inside my  controller for that [Symfony 3]:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $locale = $request->getPreferredLanguage(array('pl', 'en'));

    if($locale === "pl"){
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }else{
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage_english', array(), 301);
    }
}
```

It seems to works as expected. However, it turned out that google robots have a problem with this solution. They can't access and index my Polish pages cause they are redirected to /en as shown in example from Google Console...

[image]

I did something wrong, or maybe I shouldn't suggest a Google Console and wait a little longer ?

I'm confused... For now more than half English pages were indexed, while Polish just one - in addition, much earlier, with the previous application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hreflang links to "suggest" a page for Google. This should help with the indexing of the pages for the correct languages.

An example would be:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-ie" hreflang="en-ie" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-ca" hreflang="en-ca" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en-au" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en" hreflang="en" />
```

More information is available on Google: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Comment: Hmmm, This will signal to the google robots that page has Polish equivalent, but I'm afraid that they still won't be able to access my page. I sended a sitemap.xml so I already signaled the existence of links, but without effects. Anyway I will try

Comment: You could try to avoid the redirects and build a translation file for strings etcetera. If the url is shared amongst languages a file like that helps, if the url is not shared than it simply should not be visible for the other language. I've always learned that redirects should ideally be avoided for SEO purposes

Comment: I thought redirecting to user native language would be convenient for them, but I see that there are more downsides than advantages of this solution. I will temporarily remove redirects, until I find a better solution, or simply kind of workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome! Good luck with the implementation. If you could be so kind to accept my answer as it does help with the indexing and might help as reference for other people in the future. :)

Comment: Marked as the best answer. I was going to give a bit of time to answer from the rest Stack community.

Comment: For SEO and best practices I would just have the locale passed into the URL: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html#the-locale-and-the-url